# Limitar que una edición relance una pregunta

Tags: soporte, ediciones, relanzado-de-preguntas

Buenas tardes,

Me estoy encontrando hoy en el sitio de SO en español muchas preguntas relanzadas de prácticamente medio año atrás, estando respondidas y marcadas como tal, debido a una edición masiva por parte de un usuario, resultando en un falseo de las preguntas activas en la página principal, relegando a preguntas recién realizadas o activas a una posición inferior en la página de una manera rápida.

¿De qué manera se puede limitar esto? ¿No sería un comportamiento, llamemosle dudoso, para obtener reputación editando preguntas en las que una edición ya no aporta nada? ¿Sería posible no mostrar una pregunta como relanzada si ya ha sido marcada como respondida?

Saludos.

EDIT: Agrego una imagen. Es de hace escasos 2 minutos
[image: Preguntas editadas]

Agrego también enlace a algunas preguntas
[Pregunta 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74832/como-pintar-una-fecha-que-viene-de-una-tabla-sql-en-un-calendario-en-c)
[Pregunta 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75006/qu%C3%A9-significa-estos-requerimientos-en-web-service)
[Pregunta 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75043/como-puedo-operar-con-elementos-con-id-din%C3%A1micos-en-jquery)

Comment: Los ejemplos están en la página principal, simplemente habría que ir ahí. Yo no dudo que los ejemplos puedan llegar a ser positivos o no, si no útiles en cuanto a que la pregunta está marcada como respondida. Lo siento, no sé como adjuntaros una imagen, he aterrizado aquí hace unos días.....

Comment: Bueno, si el usuario tiene suficiente reputación para editar preguntas/respuestas, en realidad no gana reputación con ello (otra cosa es que pueda ganar medallas). Y si la edición es correcta, tampoco pasa nada por editar preguntas antiguas (de hecho,hay alguna medalla por hacerlo si no recuerdo mal). Otra cosa, en la que puedo estar de acuerdo, es que no se lancen a la pagina principal solo por eso...

Comment: Claro @Pikoh, si no digo que no aporte nada no hacerlo, si no simplemente que si la pregunta está marcada como respondida no se lancen a la página principal.

Comment: Miguel, totalmente de acuerdo con eso. Lamentablemente, me temo que no podamos hacer nada sobre el tema, ya que esto será cosa del código de StackExchange. A ver si algun moderador se informa de si es configurable, aunque lo dudo mucho

Comment: Si no te interesa ver las preguntas editadas, podés seleccionar ver [las preguntas recientes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)... Al no estar presentando qué se editó en esas publicaciones, y no sé si lo viste siquiera, ¿por qué pensar lo peor y creer que es sólo para ganar puntos? Cualquier edición idealmente mejora a la publicación, incluso en pulicaciones de hace meses que ya están aceptadas... Para ver las activas no aceptadas, sólo hay que buscar con el parámetro [`hasaccepted:no`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=hasaccepted%3ano)

Comment: @Mariano en este caso, estaban persiguiendo una medalla ;)

Comment: @gbianchi seguro, pero quise resaltar el punto de que no lo está diciendo en la pregunta.... Y si fuese ese el tema, es más sencillo: flag a moderador.

Comment: Ahora que lo dice @Mariano, de hecho creo que no nos hemos dado cuenta ya que yo diría que todo el mundo tiene por defecto [las preguntas recientes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), con lo que en realidad el problema es limitado

Comment: En ese caso muchas gracias a los 3, buscaré las opciones y modificaré esto. Un placer conocer más de esta comunidad!!

Comment: @Miguel Para más parámetros de búsqueda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: De nada Miguel, bienvenido y gracias por aportar :)

Comment: Precisamente es el hecho de que las ediciones relancen las preguntas a la página principal lo que nos permite detectar estos "abusos" y corregirlos. Es un peñazo encontrarse la página de inicio colapsada pero contribuye a que, en el infinito, ya no ocurra :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Las ediciones son en su mayoria superfluas.

Camilo ya aclaró en el chat que se dejó llevar por la emoción de ganar una medalla. Sin embargo, y esto se lo dije en el chat, estoy en desacuerdo con que alguien con suficiente reputacion como para poder editar "gratis", haga ediciones superfluas solo para ganar una medalla. Es contraprudecente para los nuevos usuarios.

Ahora yendo a tu pregunta directamente, hay formas de no ver las preguntas editadas recientemente, como comento Mariano, usando la pestaña recientes.

Y ahondando más en el caso, la pestaña preguntas activas muestra justamente eso, las preguntas que estas sufriendo algún cambio. Sin importar la antigüedad de la pregunta, se puede estar agregando información importante o se puede estar vandalizando, con lo cual deben estar activas a que las veamos todos para rescatarlas de ser necesario.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en que eran superfluas. La ludificación a veces tiene estos problemas... Una de mis publicaciones fue "afectada" y le comenté que la edición no contribuye según lo descrito en el [privilegio de editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (corregir errores gramaticales o de ortografía/clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla/corregir errores mínimos o añadir apéndices / actualizaciones a medida que la publicación envejece/añadir recursos o enlaces relacionados), que es al fin y al cabo el rasero a utilizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, y las aclaraciones a todos los participantes.